# ajax doesn't update the database

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm doing a laravel project and I want to load notification via a ajax call. I wrote a code to do it. This is my ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#notificationBar').on('click', function () {
        getNotifications();
    });

    function getNotifications(){

        var getNotificationURL = '{{ route('getNotifications') }}';
        var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';

        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url : getNotificationURL,
            data : {
                _token : token
            },
            success:function (data) {
                if(data === null){
                }else{
                    $('#notificationBar').find('#notificationDropDown').find('#tempId').append('<a style="background:#e0e0d1; margin:2px 2px;" href="'+data.username+'"><img src="'+data.url+'" class="w3-circle" style="height:40px;width:40px;margin:4px 4px;" alt="Avatar"> <b> '+data.name+'</b> '+data.msg+'</a>');

                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

and this is my route

```
Route::post('getnotifications', [
    'uses' => 'NotificationController@getNotifications',
    'as' => 'getNotifications'
]);
```

the route will direct to this method in the notification controller

```
public function getNotifications(Request $request){

    $noti = DB::table('notifications')->where('accepter', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', 1)->where('ajax_call',true)->where('important',true)->first();

    if(count($noti)>0){

        $new_noti = Notifications::find($noti->id);
        $new_noti->ajax_call = false;
        $new_noti->update();

        $notification = DB::table('notifications')->leftjoin('users','users.id','notifications.current_user')->where('id', $noti->id)->first();
        $pro_ulr = asset('/img/'.$notification->pic);

        $arr = array(
            "username" => $notification->username,
            "url" => $pro_ulr,
            "name" => $notification->name,
            "msg" => $notification->msg
        );
        return response()->json($arr);
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
```

My problem is this function isn't working as I wish. Database table doesn't update and json seems to be empty. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You should log inside the count($noti)>0 conditional, does it get in there?

Comment: sorry. i didn't get that. what do you wish me to do?

Comment: Inside this conditional: "if(count($noti)>0){" do a \Log::info('here') to see if, in the laravel log, it logs that it got inside that block of code.

Comment: your query will run only first time . will give you null from next time.

Comment: I think the problem is with ajax code. laravel log doesn't updated to Log::info('here') code

Comment: add $new_noti->save();

Comment: will it work? this is a update query.

Comment: yes replace update() with save().

Comment: oh god. thanks. it works for me ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your controller's action code, hope this will resolved your issue:

```
public function getNotifications(Request $request)
{
    $notifications = Notifications::where('accepter', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', 1)->where('ajax_call', true)->where('important', true)->get();

    if ( $notifications->count() === 0 ) {
        return null;
    }

    $newNotification            = $notifications->first();
    $newNotification->ajax_call = false;
    $newNotification->save();

    $notification = DB::table('notifications')->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', 'notifications.current_user')->where('id', $noti->id)->first();
    $pro_ulr      = asset('/img/'.$notification->pic);

    $arr = [
        "username" => $notification->username,
        "url"      => $pro_ulr,
        "name"     => $notification->name,
        "msg"      => $notification->msg,
    ];

    return response()->json($arr);

}
```

Your had an issue with, `Table::first()` you need to call `get()` instead of `first()`. Also instead of `$new_noti->update();` simply `$new_noti->save();` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has one spelling mistake.

[image]

I think that you know how to fix it. When you checking, you should enable **Chrome Developer Tool** and choose **Network** tab for verifying that that request was executed.

Comment: yeah i saw it later. but the code is still not working. database is not updating